# Android Canvas: remove/hide the portion outside the circle

Tags: android

There is something I am working on in which an image rotates around the circle & I want only overlapping part of the 2nd image... For instance take an example:

[image]

The Violet image is rotating around green one & I just want the Green image & violets overlapped part (Sea Green) How Can I do this in Android?

PS: THe violet image is not only rotating around green, its also rotating around its axis, so the intersecting part changes each time interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: http://softwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/1009/

With different PorterDuff.Mode you can achieve different effects. Here is an example of how to make an bitmap have rounded corners:

```
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), b.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint p =  new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()), borderRadius, borderRadius, p);
        p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, p);
```

Comment: b is the original bitmap in my case.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with rectangles, circles and text instead of Bitmap?

Comment: @Thracian Bitmap is the format, the others are shapes. Just change drawRoundRect to whatever shape you want.

Comment: @Heinrisch i managed to change intersection colors when background color is black,  but i want to change intersection of shapes and text to specific color. Would you mind taking a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543570/android-canvas-change-color-of-intersection-of-shapes-and-texts