# How to overlay two draw rectangles with different colors

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I just got back to an old `onDraw` code after over an year and totally forgot the intricacy of Android canvas drawing, so I hope this is an easy one. I'm drawing a bar chart and the snippet to draw the rectangle is:

```html
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        myPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGrey1));
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        for (int pos = 0; pos < barCoordLeft.size(); pos ++) {

            c.drawRect(barCoordLeft.get(pos), barCoordTop.get(pos), barCoordRight.get(pos), barCoordBottom.get(pos), myPaint);
        }
```

which works just fine, now I wanted to overlay this rectangle with a shorter one in a different color showing two metrics in one bar. I thought I can simply do this by copy and pasting the above snippet and edit it like this:

```html
        myPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGrey2));

        for (int pos = 0; pos < barCoordLeft.size(); pos ++) {

            c.drawRect(barCoordLeft.get(pos), barCoordTop.get(pos), barCoordRightSleep.get(pos), barCoordBottom.get(pos), myPaint);
        }
```

i.e. change the color and use a different ArrayList for the coordinates.

I'm still confused on how `onDraw` works, so I'm missing something obvious here wrt the flow of events.

I'm shooting for something like this, how do I approach it ?

[image: overlay bar]

P.S> The reason why I have a for loop there is a chart:

so you think the code should work i.e. changing the color inbetween? It just seems to redraw the entire thing with the second color. I know there were some gotchas with `onDraw` wrt. to this.

[image: for loop]

2.P.S> D'OH, I have to create a new `Paint` object, that was pretty obvious, now it works:

```html
        Paint myPaint2 = new Paint();
        myPaint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        myPaint2.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGrey2));
        myPaint2.setStrokeWidth(10);

        for (int pos = 0; pos < barCoordLeft.size(); pos ++) {

            c.drawRect(barCoordLeft.get(pos), barCoordTop.get(pos), barCoordRightSleep.get(pos), barCoordBottom.get(pos), myPaint2);
```

[image: with 2 objects]

Comment: Why do you have a for loop ? Just draw one rectangle **c.drawRect()**, then change color and draw another rectangle. If you want something ***wildly complex*** see my answer [Android Canvas change color of intersection of shapes and texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543570/android-canvas-change-color-of-intersection-of-shapes-and-texts/50587415#50587415)..

Comment: Now your getting it. You seem to have a problem with the size of your bar going off screen and appearing again to the left (last image, bar value 373 **and** 2nd image bar value 252). Simple scaling problem.