# Is there a way to change the colour of a text layer at its intersection with a layer having the same colour such that the intersection is visible?

Tags: swift4, calayer

[image]

I have drawn two circles with bezier path and when they intersect with the text, I want to change the colour of the area of intersection as depicted in the image above. How can I achieve this?

I thought that using compositing filter would work. I took help from : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410748-compositingfilter

I want to achieve something like the following in iOS :

- Like Apple's Measure app (Level tab)]
- [Android Canvas change color of intersection of shapes and texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543570/android-canvas-change-color-of-intersection-of-shapes-and-texts)