# Porter Duff mode that ignores Alpha and covers dest

Tags: android, drawable

I'm trying change the color of my back button programmatically during the animation of a collapsing toolbar. I want it to be fully white when its expanded, and have the app default back button color when collapsed which is a color with alpha (black at 50%).

All of the examples I've found for setting icon color suggest to use

```
setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

problem is, this respects the destination alpha which is 50%, and when I when I'm in expanded mode and try to set the color to solid white, it actually comes out to white with 50% alpha.

Which PorterDuff mode behaves exactly like `SRC_ATOP` BUT IGNORES ALPHA?

Comment: This does not answer your question and I am not going for the bounty, but here's a nice visual overview of all modes that may be of some help for you ([source](https://riptutorial.com/android/topic/377/porterduff-mode)): [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAFLb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAFLb.png)

Comment: Lots of [StackOverFlow: Porter Duff stuff here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543570/android-canvas-change-color-of-intersection-of-shapes-and-texts/50587415#50587415)

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using LightingColorFilter as opposed to PorterDuff manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<color name="black_88">#88000000</color>` for black with 50% alpha and remove alpha tag from the button.

Comment: that is what I'm doing