# Paint is not visible when we use xfermode as PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN) in Android 10

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-graphics, android-paint

I'm drawing a background color in canvas using a Paint object. I'm using xfermode as `PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN)` for this paint. The background color is visible in devices below Android 10. But when I run in Android 10 devices, the background color is not visible.

`paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN)`

I was searching for any behavior changes in Android 10 on the Android Developers site but found nothing related to paint.

Is this a bug from their side or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Probable bug but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543570/android-canvas-change-color-of-intersection-of-shapes-and-texts/50587415#50587415) for some tips